# Re asking: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8

Tags: java, maven-plugin

I am facing the error 'fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8' and I have tried almost 90% of the answers available on stack overflow or other sites but I am not able to fix it. Please help me to get out of it. Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>workdayTriggerInput</groupId>
    <artifactId>workdayTriggerPolling</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <name>WorkdayProject</name>
    <description>This is workday polling trigger</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cxf.version>3.3.2</cxf.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>TestCXF/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>TestCXF/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-m07</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.27.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.505</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried to change the version of meven plugins and also java compiler too but unfortunately I was not able to fix the error.

Here is the output of mvn -v : 
Apache Maven 3.6.0

```
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-oracle
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-58-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: What is the output of `mvn -v`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I have added above in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a JRE or JDK to compile your project? you should be using a JDK.

Maven picks the Java version from the JAVA_HOME variable and not from the PATH environment variable.

This means that even if you have JDK 8 installed but if your JAVA_HOME is still referring to JDK 1.7, then you will get this error.

source and guide: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-fix-invalid-target-release-17-18-19-or-110

Comment: In that case `mvn -v` will display the Java version mentioned in JAVA_HOME variable.